# Visual basic Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'CheckBox'. Error

Tags: vb.net

I'm receiving the error "Visual basic Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'CheckBox'." Here's the chunk of code in question

```
If cb_Surfacearea.Checked = True AndAlso cb_Volume.Checked = True Then
   Me.richtxtbox.Text = "Surface area for" & variable_sphere & " = " & cb_Surfacearea & ControlChars.NewLine & "Volume For" & variable_sphere & " = " & cb_Volume
```

Comment: You are missing the `.Text` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
richtxtbox.Text = "Surface area for" & variable_sphere & " = " & cb_Surfacearea.Text & ControlChars.NewLine & "Volume For" & variable_sphere & " = " & cb_Volume.Text
```

It's not entirely clear what context you're using this in.
I'm assuming that `cb_Volume` and `cb_Surfacearea` are checkboxes?